# How to determine the space available and taken up in a LVM2 partition?

Tags: partition, lvm

On Ubuntu installation on `/dev/sda2` I run the command:

```
df -h /dev/sda2
```

to determine the used disk space and free disk space for the Ubuntu partition. It would give an example output of:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda2       542G  384G  131G  75% /
```

This partition was not a LVM2 partition. My Fedora installation, however, is on `/dev/sda4`, a LVM2 partition. Whenever I run:

```
df -h /dev/sda4
```

on this Fedora installation I get:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs        7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /dev
```

This partition is over 365 GB in size, so I know that this isn't true. My question is quite simple: how do I determine the space available on my LVM2-encrypted `/dev/sda4` partition and the space already used up in this partition, preferably, in a single command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest option is to specify its mountpoint:

```
$ df -h /home
Filesystem                         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/fedora_skrht450s-home  180G  144G   27G  85% /home
```

The [`df(1)` manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/df.1.html) explains the behaviour you're seeing:

> `df` displays the
>          amount of disk space available on the file system containing each
>          file name argument.  If no file name is given, the space available on
>          all currently mounted file systems is shown.
>
> If an argument is the absolute file name of a disk device node
>          containing a mounted file system, `df` shows the space available on
>          that file system rather than on the file system containing the device
>          node.

So on your Ubuntu system, `/dev/sda2` is a mounted device, and the second paragraph applies. On your Fedora system, the LV isn't mounted *via* `/dev/sda4`, so you get the information for the filesystem containing `/dev/sda4`, `/dev`.

Comment: I partitioned Fedora so that I don't have a separate home partition. So your command would be `df -h /` instead. But still thanks. I'll accept when I can.

Answer (score 0):

`df` shows how much space is available *on a filesystem*. There are two ways to specify a filesystem to query: you can pass a block device that is currently mounted, and `df` reports on the filesystem on that block device; otherwise, the argument can be the name of any file and `df` reports on the filesystem containing that file; or you can pass .

When `/dev/sda4` is not a block device containing a mounted filesystem , `df /dev/sda4` treats `/dev/sda4` as a generic file (second case above) and reports on the filesystem containing it, which is `/dev`. On your Fedora system, `/dev/sda4` contains an LVM physical volume; this is not a filesystem. To use the device syntax of `df`, you would need to pass the device containing the filesystem, which is an LVM logical volume: something like `df /dev/mapper/groupname-logicalvolumename` or `df /dev/groupname/logicalvolumename`.

If you want to know how much space is available on the root filesystem, just use `df /`